# The equation in product space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces and continous mappings $f: X \rightarrow Y$, $g:X \rightarrow Z$ and $\varphi=(f,g): X\rightarrow Y\times Z, \varphi(x)=(f(x),g(x)),\forall x\in X$. With $x_0$ be an abitrary point in $X$ and $U$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$. I wonder if $\varphi (U)=f(U) \times g(U)$ is true or it's just $\varphi(U) \subset f(U) \times g(U)$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X=Y=Z$ and $f(x)=g(x)=x,$ then $f(U)=\{(x,y)\in U\times U| x=y\}\neq U\times U,$ if $U$ has more than one element. Hence, you can't expect more than inclusion in general. I guess the heuristic is that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ might not be independent (here, I can obviously predict the value of $g$ just knowing that value of $f$).

Comment: More geometrically, $X$ could be $[0,1]$, so that $f$ and $g$ are paths in $Y$ and $Z$. If these are manifolds, then the images of $f$ and $g$ are, intuitively speaking, one-dimensional objects in $Y$ and $Z$. However, that's still true of $(f,g)$ (it's still a path in $Y\times Z$ and hence "one-dimensional"). But $f(X)\times f(Y)$ is a product of two one-dimensional objects and hence, should be "two-dimensional".

Comment: So it's just $\varphi(U) \subset f(U) \times g(U)$, right ?

Comment: Yes. $(f(x),g(x))$ definitely belongs to $f(U)\times g(U)$ if $x\in U$, so you automatically have this inclusion.